# Finding variables that contributes the most for a decision tree prediction in H2o

Tags: decision-tree, h2o

How to find the variables that contributes the most for a particular prediction in case of a decision tree? For eg. If there are features A,B,C,D,E and we build a decision tree on top of the dataset. Then for a sample x, lets say variables C,D contributes the most to the prediction(x). How to find these variables that contributed the most for prediction(x) in H2O? I know the H2O gives global importance of variables once the decision tree is built. My question applies in the case when we are using that particular tree to make a decision and in finding the variables that contributed to that particular decision. Scikit learn has functions to extract the rules that were used to predict a sample. Does H2O have any such functionality?

Comment: That will depend on what you mean by "contribution". Do you have an application in mind or are you just exploring the properties of decision trees?

Comment: This question is specific to H2O. By contribution I mean which features had the most influence in making a particular decision.

Answer (score 0):

H2O has no support for doing this currently (as of Feb 2017, h2o 3.10.3.x); Erin opened a JIRA for it: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4007